# How to clear SFML-Image very fast? C++

Tags: c++, sfml

I have a big SFML-Image. I want to set all pixels as `sf::Color(0,0,0,0)`.

If I use `img.create(img.getSize().x, img.getSize().y, sf::Color(0, 0, 0, 0));` then the method calls the `new` operator.
If I try to use `img.getPixelsPtr()` then I get a pointer to **const** array.

But how I can to use `memset(pixels, 0, sizex*sizey*sizeof(sf::Color))`, without using the `new` operator?

Answer (score 1):

pretty sure you have to loop over the entire array of pixels with setPixel, I recall Laurent talking about possibly adding a way to access the underlaying array directly in the future

edit:
https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=1772.0 turns out it was 2009 when he said that (reply #4)

edit2:
you can also cast away the constness of the pointer i think

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::Image image;
    image.create(800u, 600u);

    image.saveToFile("test0.png");

    auto px0 = const_cast<sf::Uint8*>(image.getPixelsPtr());

    std::fill(px0, px0 + image.getSize().x * image.getSize().y * 4, 0xFFu);

    image.saveToFile("test1.png");

    auto px1 = reinterpret_cast<sf::Color*>(const_cast<sf::Uint8*>(image.getPixelsPtr()));

    std::fill(px1, px1 + image.getSize().x * image.getSize().y, sf::Color::Red);

    image.saveToFile("test2.png");
}
```